# What is the meaning of form action="/"?

Tags: php, html

action of a form normally refers to the script which runs after submittting. I saw a code with   `form action="/"` and I am unable to find to where it goes. Someone please explain me.

Comment: It sends the form data to the index page or the home page of that site where the form is.
Here, [Try it yourself](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It goes to the index of the base dir.

Comment: No! It refers to the index page of the *base*dir!

Comment: If someone did set the baseURL indeed. Changed my answer just for you, thanks for the addition :)(

Answer (score 1):

It mean to index page of the site.

Answer (score 1):

It sends the form to the index page of the site. (normally index.php, but often index.html, or main.html)

Answer (score 0):

See it as an directory. The / just means that your application will search in the very first directory for an index.php file.