# ColdFusion Form with action ="/"

Tags: forms, server, coldfusion, mapping

I have read through everything I can find and have been programming in CF over 20 years.  I am trying to figure out why there is an error in a library that I am working with.  The form has an action of "/".  I have never seen this before.  It is submitting it to the root of my server and I have no idea what to do with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've never seen that before either, but a quick search turned up this. The form action gets sent to the site index.
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022150/what-is-the-meaning-of-form-action

Comment: Thanks!  I swear I searched for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of form action="/"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022150/what-is-the-meaning-of-form-action)

Answer (score 2):

If your Server having the `index.cfm` file means the form will submit to the index.cfm otherwise it will redirect to the root folder. So I guess the index.cfm file not be there.

I'm not able to add as comment, So that I've added as answer. Hope it will help someone.